# Adding up integers php

Tags: php, wordpress, navigation

I am attempting to add up all the string lengths of each menu item I have so I can have a character limit for my entire navigation rather than a set limit on each item.

I am currently using the Walker_Nav_Menu in WordPress. I can get each individual length but I can't add them all together in one variable.

First I check to see if the item is a main header not a sub menu and then use strlen to get the length of the text.

```
class top_bar_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
        global $wp_query;


            if( $item->menu_item_parent == 0 ) {
            $length = strlen( $item->title );

            }


            var_dump($length);




        $indent = ($depth) ? str_repeat("\t", $depth) : '';

        $class_names = $value = '';

        $classes = empty($item->classes) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

        $classes[] = ($item->current) ? 'active' : '';
        $classes[] = ($args->has_children) ? 'has-dropdown' : '';

        $args->link_before = (in_array('section', $classes)) ? '<label>' : '';
        $args->link_after = (in_array('section', $classes)) ? '</label>' : '';
        $output .= (in_array('section', $classes)) ? '<li class="divider"></li>' : '';

        $class_names = join(' ', apply_filters('nav_menu_css_class', array_filter($classes), $item, $args ) );
        $class_names = strlen(trim($class_names)) > 0 ? ' class="'.esc_attr($class_names).'"' : '';

        $output .= ($depth == 0) ? $indent.'<li class="divider"></li>' : '';
        $output .= $indent.'<li id="menu-item-'.$item->ID.'"'.$value.$class_names.'>';

        $attributes  = !empty($item->attr_title) ? ' title="' .esc_attr($item->attr_title).'"' : '';
        $attributes .= !empty($item->target)     ? ' target="'.esc_attr($item->target    ).'"' : '';
        $attributes .= !empty($item->xfn)        ? ' rel="'   .esc_attr($item->xfn       ).'"' : '';
        $attributes .= !empty($item->url)        ? ' href="'  .esc_attr($item->url       ).'"' : '';


        $item_output  = $args->before;
        $item_output .= (!in_array('section', $classes)) ? '<a'.$attributes.'>' : '';
        // Find out if menu item is top level. If character size is greater than 15, cut down string and add '..''
        $item_output .= $args->link_before.($item->menu_item_parent == 0 && strlen( $item->title ) > 10 ) ?  trim( substr( apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ), 0, 10 ) ).".." : apply_filters('the_title', $item->title, $item->ID);
        $item_output .= $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= (!in_array('section', $classes)) ? '</a>' : '';
        $item_output .= $args->after;



        $output .= apply_filters('walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args);
    }
```

When I do a var dump of $length I get

```
int(38) NULL NULL int(32) NULL int(16) NULL int(18) NULL int(42) NULL int(20) NULL
```

But i am unable to add them together

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What errors are you getting, specifically?

Comment: When I do a var_dump on length i get int(38) NULL NULL int(32) NULL int(16) NULL int(18) NULL int(42) NULL int(20) NULL , Is it possible to add all those ints together?

Comment: Without seeing more of your code, I'm not sure where it would be going wrong.  If what you showed there is inside a foreach loop, make sure you're adding $length to a different variable after determining length, as setting $length to the result of strlen() each time will only, at the end of the foreach loop, cause $length to be equal to the value of the last item iterated.

Comment: Was this from within the foreach?  PHP will add all those up fine without even checking for NULL's.  Perhaps you could post with the foreach to make the question clearer?

Comment: When you got the white screen, what error was stored in the PHP error log? Perhaps $item->menu_item_parent caused the error if $item was not an object. Try checking that $item is a valid object before trying to access its properties.  You can use is_object($item) to check.

Comment: After doing is_object i get bool(true) bool(true) bool(true) bool(true) bool(true) bool(true) bool(true) bool(true) bool(true) bool(true) bool(true) bool(true) bool(true), could the function already be looping through $item?

Comment: Again, it'd be infinitely helpful to see what is in the PHP error log...